# How to terminate async execution of dispatch queue in swift?

Tags: swift

I am currently using Particle's API for event streaming, and I wish to terminate the event subscription at some unknown point in time(I know there is an interface for timed termination).

```
ParticleCloud.sharedInstance().subscribeToAllEvents(withPrefix: prefix, handler: { (eventOpt :ParticleEvent?, error : Error?) in
            if let _ = error {
                eprint (message: "Could not subscribe to events")
            } else {
                let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "foo")
                serialQueue.async(execute: {
                    ...
                })
            }
        })
```

From what I know, the `DispatchQueue` object in swift takes vacant threads from the pool and runs the function I have omitted(because it's irrelevant to the problem). I would want some way of ending the `.async` call later, as it's running indefinitely right now.

I looked around stack overflow for possibilities of suspending or resuming the dispatch queue later on, for example:

```
ParticleCloud.sharedInstance().subscribeToAllEvents(withPrefix: prefix, handler: { (eventOpt :ParticleEvent?, error : Error?) in
            if let _ = error {
                eprint (message: "Could not subscribe to events")
            } else {
                let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "foo")
                serialQueue.async(execute: {
                    ...
                })
                serialQueue.suspend() // EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
            }
        })
```

But it resulted in a `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`. The diagnosis (nil objects, etc) was not helpful.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to give an MVCE example of this problem because it requires the particle hardware and a registered account on particle.io, so I apologize for that.

The API for `subscribeToAllEvents` is here: https://docs.particle.io/reference/ios/#events-sub-system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the documentation for `subscribeToAllEventsWithPrefix:handler:`:

> **Returns:** eventListenerID function will return an id type object as the eventListener registration unique ID - keep and pass this object to the unsubscribe method in order to remove this event listener

It's confusingly written, but the gist is that the subscribe function returns an object. You should keep the object in an instance property. When you're ready to unsubscribe, pass the object to the unsubscribe function.

So:

```
// Instance property.
var subscription: Any?

subscription = ParticleCloud.sharedInstance().subscribeToAllEvents(withPrefix: prefix, handler: { ... })

// When it's time to unsubscribe...
if let subscription = subscription {
    ParticleCloud.sharedInstance().unsubscribeFromEvent(withID: subscription)
    self.subscription = nil
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! The particle documentation is indeed confusing to me, thank you for elaborating :)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this is to use an `OperationQueue` instead of a `DispatchQueue`. Add a `BlockOperation` to the queue and keep a reference to the operation, and then you can call `cancel` on the operation to prevent it from executing (if the operation has already started, however, this won't stop it, so if this is a concern you could have its closure periodically check its `isCancelled` property and exit early if it finds `true`).